# Running Flask app.py works from Terminal, but not from PyCharm

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to get the hang of Flask. I specifically want to learn using Flask with PyCharm.

I have set up the minimal example from the [Flask website](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/). When I run it from the terminal with `flask run` it works, which means I can open up the website.

When I run from PyCharm, it also seems to work, but I get an 404 error when I try to open up the site.

Am I missing some configuration in PyCharm?

Here's the `app.py` file:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe in Pycharm everything runs in a virtual environment. That is why you cannot access your site. Try going to http://localhost:5000 while the app is running in Pycharm. If that doesn't work try it from the terminal. If it works in the terminal then come back to this answer and reply that it doesn't work.

Comment: Good point–I still have to wrap my head around python environments... I did create a local (to the project) env via the terminal. That env is set up in PyCharm as the env as well. I just tried, neither 127.0.0.1:5000 nor localhost:5000 works from PyCharm, both do work from terminal.